# How to interpret the output of MuMIn model.avg on GAMs

Tags: r, gam, mumin

Say I have a series of GAMs that I would like to average together using `MuMIn`. How do I go about interpreting the results of the averaged smoothers? Why are there numbers after each smoother term?

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(mgcv)
library(MuMIn)

data("Salamanders") # glmmTMB data

# mgcv gams
gam1 <- gam(count ~ spp + s(cover) + s(DOP), data = Salamanders, family = tw, method = "ML")
gam2 <- gam(count ~ mined + s(cover) + s(DOP), data = Salamanders, family = tw, method = "ML")
gam3 <- gam(count ~ s(Wtemp), data = Salamanders, family = tw, method = "ML")
gam4 <- gam(count ~ mined + s(DOY), data = Salamanders, family = tw, method = "ML")

# MuMIn model average
summary(model.avg(gam1, gam2, gam3, gam4))
```

And an excerpt from the results...

```
Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
                                                Estimate                                   Std. Error
(Intercept) -1.32278368618846586812765053764451295137405  0.16027398202204409805027296442858641967177
minedno      2.22006553885311141982583649223670363426208  0.19680444996609294805445244946895400062203
s(cover).1   0.00096638939252485735100645092288118576107  0.05129736767981037115493592182247084565461
s(cover).2   0.00360413985630353601863351542533564497717  0.18864911049300209233692271482141222804785
s(cover).3   0.00034381902619062468381624930735540601745  0.01890820689958183642431777116144075989723
s(cover).4  -0.00248365164684107844403349041328965540743  0.12950622739175629560826052966149291023612
s(cover).5  -0.00089826079366626997504963192398008686723  0.04660149540411069601919535898559843190014
s(cover).6   0.00242197856572917875894734862640689243563  0.12855093144749979439112053114513400942087
s(cover).7  -0.00032596616013735266745646179664674946252  0.02076865732570042782922925539423886220902
s(cover).8   0.00700001172809289889942263584998727310449  0.36609857217759655956257347497739829123020
s(cover).9  -0.17150069832114492318630993850092636421323  0.17672571419517621449379873865836998447776
s(DOP).1     0.00018839994220792031023870016781529557193  0.01119134546418791391342306695833030971698
s(DOP).2    -0.00081869157242861999301819508900734945200  0.04333670935815417402103832955617690458894
s(DOP).3    -0.00021538789478326670289408395486674407948  0.01164171952980479901595955993798270355910
s(DOP).4     0.00043433676942596419591827161532648915454  0.02463278659589070856972270462392771150917
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a little easier to read if you don't print so many digits (see below):

Each smooth term is parameterized using multiple coefficients (9 by default), which is why we have multiple `s.(whatever).xxx` coefficients.

It's not clear to me what you want to do with the model-averaged results. It's usually best to make model-averaged **predictions** rather than trying to interpret model-averaged coefficients, which has some pitfalls ... There is a `predict()` method for objects of class "averaging" (which is what `model.average()` returns).

For further questions about **interpretation** you might want to ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) ...

```r
Model-averaged coefficients:  
(full average) 
              Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -1.323e+00  1.603e-01   1.606e-01   8.239   <2e-16 ***
minedno      2.220e+00  1.968e-01   1.971e-01  11.263   <2e-16 ***
s(cover).1   9.664e-04  5.130e-02   5.130e-02   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).2   3.604e-03  1.886e-01   1.887e-01   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).3   3.438e-04  1.891e-02   1.891e-02   0.018    0.985    
s(cover).4  -2.484e-03  1.295e-01   1.295e-01   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).5  -8.983e-04  4.660e-02   4.660e-02   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).6   2.422e-03  1.286e-01   1.286e-01   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).7  -3.260e-04  2.077e-02   2.078e-02   0.016    0.987    
s(cover).8   7.000e-03  3.661e-01   3.661e-01   0.019    0.985    
s(cover).9  -1.715e-01  1.767e-01   1.768e-01   0.970    0.332    
s(DOP).1     1.884e-04  1.119e-02   1.120e-02   0.017    0.987    
s(DOP).2    -8.187e-04  4.334e-02   4.334e-02   0.019    0.985    
s(DOP).3    -2.154e-04  1.164e-02   1.164e-02   0.018    0.985    
s(DOP).4     4.343e-04  2.463e-02   2.464e-02   0.018    0.986    
s(DOP).5    -1.737e-04  1.019e-02   1.020e-02   0.017    0.986    
s(DOP).6    -3.224e-04  1.790e-02   1.790e-02   0.018    0.986    
s(DOP).7     2.991e-07  5.739e-04   5.750e-04   0.001    1.000    
s(DOP).8    -1.756e-03  9.557e-02   9.559e-02   0.018    0.985    
s(DOP).9     1.930e-02  5.630e-02   5.639e-02   0.342    0.732    
s(DOY).1     5.189e-08  3.378e-04   3.384e-04   0.000    1.000
```

Comment: Ah, so this is `k` in action then. Thanks. We are interested in seeing the effect of each covariate on a population of birds, following an IT approach similar to Whittingham et al 2006 & Grueber et al 2011, which works well with our GLMMs. I was curious if something similar could be done with GAMs so was just playing around with the code & dataset but it is a bit beyond my understanding. The GAM smoothers are just a better fit for seasonal effects.

Comment: @spops I honestly don't think this way of model fitting is a good thing to do; if you know enough about the system to model some effects as smooth, but you're also willing to fit models where you state those effects are exactly 0, really doesn't make sense to me. Assuming you have a set of well-chosen covariates (from theory or previous work), then I would fit the full GAM (with all those well chosen covariates as smooths, with well-chosen `k` stated for each) and use `select = TRUE` (to add an extra shrinkage penalty) or add `bs = "ts"` to any smooth you want to do selection on.

Comment: I am not stating those effects are exactly zero. 'Day of season' is a quadratic effect, `dos + I(dos^2)`, and works well in the linear models. The choice of the models is beyond me - I'm just doing what they tell me to do - but I was curious about how well a GAM might fit the data and had some time to test it out. The results between the two sets of models are largely the same so this was more of a thought exercise. Thanks for your suggestions, I will keep them in mind.

Comment: @spops You are saying effects are exactly zero (or at least you are allowing mumin to state this for you); what do you think a model that *excludes* `mined` or `s(cover)` say, encodes about the value of the effect of `mined` or `s(cover)`? It encodes that the effect is zero. This has nothing to do with GAMs (although I also find it philosophically dubious to fit a GLM where we think the effect != 0 and then a model where the effect is === 0, unless we are doing this purely for prediction), but it is more problematic when doing this with smooth function. 1/2

Comment: @spops Doing something just because someone tells you to do it is not a good way to do statistics and unfortunately there is a lot of this "folklore" in ecology. And yes, I recognize the irony of my telling you not to do what those other people tell you to do :-) If you are trying to get a predictive model, then model averaging predictions is not fundamentally flawed. If you are trying to learn something about your data/system etc then doing this kind of averaging of functions (coefficients) is flawed. 2/2